# Show that $f(z) = z^2 \overline z$ is not analytical anywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z) = z^2 \overline z$ is not analytical anywhere, i.e. $f(z) = z^2 \overline z$ is non holomorphic anywhere.

I think I am supposed to use Cauchy-Riemann equations but not sure how to.

Comment: The question is wrong: the derivative does exist at one point.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Probably the standard student confusion between $f$ being analytic and differentiable at one point....

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** 
$$f(z)=z^2 \bar{z}=z(z \bar{z})=z |z|^2$$

Writing $z=x+iy$ you get

$$f(x+iy)=(x+iy)(x^2+y^2) $$

Now use the CR Riemann Equations, you will find out that $f$ is differentiable only at one point.

**Alternate solution:** If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on some domain $D$, then $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is holomoorphic on the domain $D \setminus \{ 0 \}$. But  $\frac{f(z)}{z}=|z|^2$ only takes real values...

Comment: Since f is only differentiable at one point, does that mean it is not analytical anywhere?

Comment: @user132568 Yes. Analytic at some point means differentiable on an open set around that point.

Comment: So, i've gone by the definition of holomorphic and taken the limit as z tends to z0 of (f(z)-f(z0))/(z-z0). So far, i have got [(z*mod(z^2))-(z0*mod(z0^2))]/(z-z0). I am not quite sure what to do next?

Comment: @user132568 Using the definition is complicated. Just use the CR-equations. You'll discover that the CR fail excepting at one point. This proves that $f$ can only be differentiable at at most that point.